# React Apollo Client - query results mixing up in cache

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I use apollo client to fetch book graphs and use relay style pagination. Both of the following `NEW_BOOKS` query and `ALL_BOOKS` query works fine independently.

Currently, I am using `NEW_BOOKS` in the home page and `ALL_BOOKS` in a popup in the home page.
When the Homepage is opened `NEW_BOOKS` gets loaded fine.
When the popup is opened and `ALL_BOOKS` is fetched, `newBooks` become `undefined` or the result of `ALL_BOOKS` query.

Why is this happening?

```
const { loading, data: newBooks, fetchMore, networkStatus } = useQuery(NEW_BOOKS, {
    variables: {
        first: PAGE_SIZE,
        after: endCursor
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
});

const NEW_BOOKS = gql`query GetNewBooks($first:Int!, $after:String){
    books(
        first: $first, after: $after,
        filters: [
            {
                path: "isNew",
                value: true
            }
        ]
    ) {
        totalCount
        pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            startCursor
            endCursor
        }
        edges {
            node {
                id
                name
                author {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`;
```

-All books query filterable by name

```
const { loading, data: filteredBooks, fetchMore, networkStatus } = useQuery(ALL_BOOKS, {
    variables: {
        first: PAGE_SIZE,
        after: endCursor,
        name: nameFilter
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
});

const ALL_BOOKS = gql`query GetAllBooks($first:Int!, $after:String, $name:String){
    books(
        first: $first, after: $after,
        filters: [
            {
                path: "name",
                value: $name,
                type: "contains"
            }
        ]
    ) {
        totalCount
        pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            startCursor
            endCursor
        }
        edges {
            node {
                id
                name
                copiesSold
                author {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`;
```

The cache being used looks like this,

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
        Query: {
            fields: {
                books: relayStylePagination(),
            },
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to pass `keyArgs` explictly when `relayStylePagination` or similar pagination is used.

A `keyArgs: ["type"]` field policy configuration means type is the only argument the cache should consider (in addition to the field name and the identity of the enclosing object) when accessing values for this field. A `keyArgs: false` configuration disables the whole system of differentiating field values by arguments, so the field's value will be identified only by the field's name (within some `StoreObject`), without any serialized arguments appended to it.

[KeyArgs documentation here.](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/key-args/)

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
        Query: {
            fields: {
                books: relayStylePagination(["name"]),
            },
        }
    },
});
```